# How can I use par as my paragraph formatter

Tags: formatting, fill-paragraph

I'm coming from vim, which has a `gq` operator that acts much like emacs' `fill-paragraph` function (`M-q`). There's a `'formatprg'` setting that allows you to point `gq` at an external program for its formatting decisions, and I've found that using [par](http://www.nicemice.net/par/) yields much nicer results than vim's default formatting logic.

I'd like to do something equivalent in emacs (get it to use par). I see there's a `fill-paragraph-function` variable, and I know that basically *anything* is possible in emacs, but I'm not sure how to go about wiring it in. How could I do so?

Comment: I've never used it, but the basic steps would be to write a wrapper function that a) finds the bounds of the paragraph, b) sends the characters within those bounds to `par` for processing, c) takes the formatted text returned by `par`, and d) replaces the original text with the new text.

Comment: Paragraph filling in emacs is handled in major modes. It's possible, and relatively straight forward, to mark a paragraph and run `par` on it, and have the return value replace the old paragraph. However, this approach is at odds with normal practice, and you might end up with a brittle amalgam of custom code that needs to be updated for each mode you use. Before going down that route, perhaps you can see if the built-in paragraph filling features can be tweaked to do what you want.

Comment: TIL about the `par` utility; it's `man` page is beautifully written. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Essentially you want your function to do the equivalent of marking the paragraph and typing <kbd>C-u</kbd><kbd>M-|</kbd> `par` <kbd>RET</kbd>

Something like:

```el
(defun my-fill-paragraph-using-par (&optional _justify)
  "Invoke shell command `par' on the current paragraph."
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (mark-paragraph)
    (forward-whitespace 1)
    (shell-command-on-region (point) (mark) "par" nil :replace))
  t) ;; Don't return nil. See variable `fill-paragraph-function'.
```

Answer (score 4):

Here I have taken what **@phils** had posted and have modified it to:

- Take more `par` options
- Apply `par` formatting only on the region, without limiting to paragraph marking because `mark-paragraph` relies on the major mode to work correctly.
- Attempt to make this work on code comments (by marking `comment-start` characters as *Quote characters* for `par`).
- Attempt to handle `par` errors more gracefully and try not to mess up the user's original buffer in the event of error

### How to use the below code

1. Evaluate the below code
2. `M-h M-H` if you want to fill the region in a paragraph

### Code

```el
;; par - http://www.nicemice.net/par/
(when (executable-find "par")
  (defun modi/par-fill-region (begin end par-option)
    "Use `par' executable to fill region between BEGIN and END.

If PAR-OPTION is \\='(4) `\\[universal-argument]', also justify the text.
If PAR-OPTION is \\='(16) `\\[universal-argument] \\[universal-argument]', try to
make all lines of almost equal lengths instead of justifying.

See `man par' for more information."
    (interactive "r\nP")
    (let* ((width-str (number-to-string fill-column))
           (err-buf "*par Error*")
           (par-cmd
            (concat "par "
                    "w" width-str " " ; set fill width
                    ;; Body characters: . , ? upper-case lower-case
                    (shell-quote-argument "B=.,?_A_a") " "
                    ;; Quote characters: space > | <comment-start char>
                    (shell-quote-argument
                     (concat "Q=_s>|" (when comment-start comment-start))) " "
                     ;; Allow bodiless characters like *, space, .. to inc/dec by
                     ;; up to 10 characters to adjust line width.
                     "r10"
                     "T4" ; Expand tab chars to 4 spaces
                     ;; Prefixes may not contain any trailing body characters, and
                     ;; suffixes may not contain any leading body characters
                     "b"
                     "e" ; Expel/remove superfluous lines
                     (when (equal '(16) par-option)
                       "f") ; Try to make all lines of nearly the same length
                     "g" ; Make a better guess at inserting line breaks
                     (when (equal '(4) par-option)
                       "j") ; Justify the lines by inserting spaces between words
                     "q" ; Insert blank lines before/after quoted text
                     "R" ; Throw an error if a word length exceeds the fill width
                     "E" )) ; Send error to stderr instead of stdout
           (before-text (buffer-substring-no-properties begin end))
           par-ret
           ;; Do the formatting in a temp buffer so that the text in the original
           ;; buffer doesn't get corrupted in case `par' fails due to some error.
           (after-text (with-temp-buffer
                         (insert before-text)
                         (setq par-ret (shell-command-on-region
                                        (point-min) (point-max)
                                        par-cmd nil :replace
                                        err-buf :display-error-buffer))
                         (buffer-substring-no-properties (point-min) (point-max)))))
      ;; If 1 is returned, error occurred in the cmd execution; 0 - no error
      (if (= 1 par-ret)
          (progn
            ;; Switch to the error buffer
            (switch-to-buffer-other-window err-buf)
            (special-mode)) ; Set this mode so that you can quit it quickly using C-u q
        ;; If no error occurred, do below in the original buffer 
        (delete-region begin end)
        (insert after-text))
      (message "Executed `%s' on the region" par-cmd)))
  ;; Rationale for the below binding is that it flows very well when selecting a
  ;; paragraph and then filling that region: "M-h M-H"
  (global-set-key (kbd "M-H") #'modi/par-fill-region))
```

Comment: Very cool! I accepted @phils answer since it was the original, but thanks for contributing. There's a lot I can learn from here.

Comment: Very nice. You should make this into a MELPA package, it improves Emacs' fill nicely